# How to populate select tag with mysql data and then show it in html table?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am having trouble with my HTML/PHP table i am trying to populate html select tag 
with data from database and show it in table. But select tag with database data is only shown in first row of the table.
Here is my code:

```
$result2  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT vozac FROM vozaci");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT registracija,tip,status,vozac,napomena2,IDV FROM status_vozila order by status desc")

or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<form action="" method="post">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['registracija'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['tip'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>
  <select name="statusi">
  <option value="Na parkingu" name="Na parkingu">Na parkingu</option>
  <option value="Na turi" name="Na turi">Na turi</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici" name="Potreban radionici">Potreban radionici</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici-na parkingu" name="Potreban radionici-na parkingu">Potreban radionici-na parkingu</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici-na turi" name="Potreban radionici-na putu">Potreban radionici-na turi</option>
  <option value="Razvoz" name="Razvoz">Razvoz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['vozac'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<select name="list">';

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $row['vozac'] .'">' . $row['vozac'] .'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['napomena2'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="napomena2" value=""><input type="submit" name="update3" value="Dodaj" /></td>';
  echo'<td><input type="hidden" name="IDV" value="'.$row['IDV'].'"></td>';

  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</form>';
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: try to run your query on database, I think you may have only one record

Comment: If it's only shown in the first row, what were you expecting? To have a select element in every row? Or do you mean you're only getting one result *in* the select ?

Comment: @ProElviz I am trying to have a select element in every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `row` variable. in other loop change variable name

```
 while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $row1['vozac'] .'">' . $row1['vozac'] .'</option>';
  }
```

Also You need to store all values in one array first then traverse it. Instead of calling same query multiple times. Once your data is fetched. It will not execute again until you call (`mysqli_query()`) query again.

**edit**

I already mention that *store all values in one array first then traverse it*. Try this code:

```
$result2  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT vozac FROM vozaci");
$list_vozaci = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  $list_vozaci[] = $row['vozac'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT registracija,tip,status,vozac,napomena2,IDV FROM status_vozila order by status desc")

or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<form action="" method="post">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['registracija'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['tip'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>
  <select name="statusi">
  <option value="Na parkingu" name="Na parkingu">Na parkingu</option>
  <option value="Na turi" name="Na turi">Na turi</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici" name="Potreban radionici">Potreban radionici</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici-na parkingu" name="Potreban radionici-na parkingu">Potreban radionici-na parkingu</option>
  <option value="Potreban radionici-na turi" name="Potreban radionici-na putu">Potreban radionici-na turi</option>
  <option value="Razvoz" name="Razvoz">Razvoz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['vozac'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<select name="list">';

  foreach ($list_vozaci as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value .'">' . $value .'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['napomena2'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="napomena2" value=""><input type="submit" name="update3" value="Dodaj" /></td>';
  echo'<td><input type="hidden" name="IDV" value="'.$row['IDV'].'"></td>';

  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</form>';
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Even when i change $row to $row1 it stills show populated select tag in first row @B.Desai

Comment: Filip, read carefully. "Once your data is fetched. It will not execute again until you call (mysqli_query()) query again."

Comment: @FilipDjordjevic have read my answer carefully? I have stated that **Once your data is fetched. It will not execute again until you call (mysqli_query()) query again.**

Comment: @B.Desai i have a question about foreach loop, is it possible to something like this: echo '<option value="' . $row['vozac'] .''.$row['broj'].'">' . $row['vozac'] .'</option>'; with foreach loop? this echo work in while loop but i dont quite get foreach loop.